# Change permission on Content Overview page

Tags: users

I have granted an admin 'Administer Content' permission under People->Permissions. This gives him the ability to publish/unpublish nodes. But I don't want him to be able to go to the Content overview page where he can delete and unpublish in bulk. This is because I have setup certain workflow rules with node_validate which only let him delete or unpublish nodes under certain conditions within the node edit screen. If he goes to the Content overview page, he can circumvent the workflow logic.

So how do I programmatically take 'Administer Content' permission away when he goes to the Content overview page? I still want him to be able to see the Content overview, but I don't want him to be able to unpublish, delete, or do any of the other bulk operations.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is such an old question, but I had the same question and hiding it in css is not the answer.

The correct answer IS to enable the Actions permissions (VBO) (actions_permissions) module.  That will allow you to set which roles can perform bulk operations.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure there isn't a way to accomplish this.

Maybe you could use css and hide the Edit Options field set like this:

```
#edit-options {
  display: none;
}
```

That would hide it, but if he was malicious he could edit the CSS in his browser and then use it.